# xcode 6 Preview Assistant Editor table view gives false preview

Tags: iphone, ios8, xcode6

I'm using xcode 6.2 and testing on iphone 6.
on storyboard i design for size classes: width = compact, height = regular (i.e. all iphones in portrait) and i have a table view (dynamic prototypes) controller with custom cells i've designed.

The preview editor's iphone 4.7 inch preview differs from what i get when i run on an acctual iphone 6. it actually looks like the preview editor's iphone 4 inch preview.

any ideas?

Comment: make sure you have proper launch images for 4.7 inch device

Comment: why do you think the launch image should have any impact on they way the UI looks on the screen later?

Comment: if you don't have launch image of required resolution, your app will run in compatibility mode and everything will look scaled.